# Is Freelancer set in the StarLancer universe?

Tags: freelancer, starlancer

**Is Freelancer set in the StarLancer universe?**  The games have similar titles, similar styles, and similar technology.  For jump gates a prevalent in Freelancer and appear at the end of StarLancer.  There are a lot of things that seem to tie them together, but I haven't seen anything stating that they occur in the same universe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are set in the same universe.  Freelancer takes place after the Alliance/Coalition war from Starlancer.  As the Alliance realizes they are losing the war, they launch a set of sleeper ships into deep space to rebuild and recolonize outside the Sol system.  800 years later, the descendants of these colonists form the factions in the Freelancer storyline.

The intro movie to Freelancer explains this best:

There's also an explanation in the "plot and setting" section of the [Freelancer Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freelancer_%28video_game%29), and in the [Starlancer article on the Freelancer Wiki](http://freelancer.wikia.com/wiki/Starlancer).

Comment: neat, that's something I didn't know

Comment: That trailer actually was never released fully by Microsoft or Digital Anvil when the game was being released. The presence of the Nomads would come out as a spoiler.